# How to set SubType PPPoE Required for PPP over Ethernet services on OSX

Tags: macos, ppp, pppoe

Mac OSX - OS - Network

I want to create a pppoe network interface in the networkset with SCNetworkConfiguration API, but I did many times for it just create modem interface.
Anyone get the same problem or have a solution about it? Thanks
Happy new year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just easy, I try n times debug it and find the answer.
I'll put it on github
https://github.com/cppfun/mac-pppoe

Comment: all just here [https://github.com/cppfun/mac-pppoe](https://github.com/cppfun/mac-pppoe)